# Изменение города в битрикс по GET-параметру

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Проблема такая: Есть сайт на CMS Битрикс, подключена мультирегиональность без поддоменов. Нужно менять город по GET-параметру (?cid=19207 и ?cid=25907), всего 2 города.

Я дописал функционал модуля мультирегиональности, город меняется, но проблема в том, что робот Яндекс видит первые появившиеся мета-теги города, которые не всегда верные.
Как сейчас происходит процесс смены города:
город 1 -> скрипт смотрит на GET -> город 2, если параметр передается 2 города
А требуется сделать так:
Скрипт смотрит GET-параметр -> Загружает нужный город

Помогите, пожалуйста, всю голову сломал(